# Object.innerHTML not setting value

Tags: javascript

I am using object.innertHTML to set an HTML structure. But its not setting initial TR and TD elements.. Below is the code

```
 var previousInnerHTML = new String();
 previousInnerHTML = previousInnerHTML.concat("<TR class='evenrow ' __eventAdded='true' isSubTotalRow='false' usable='false' index='40'><TD><INPUT id=check_table1 onclick=WebForm.markRowForSelection(event) type=checkbox xformstype='checkbox' doEBIValidate='false' __cID='c514' transactional='true' model='null' freemodel='false' databound='true' freeform='false' _initialized='true' originalTitle dataBoundElement='true' selectnotifier='true' trueValue='null' falseValue='null'></INPUT></TD><TD><DIV id=xfe2 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output2 class=input title='Provide value for Output2' type=text xformstype='input' doEBIValidate='false' __parent='table1' __cID='c515' transactional='true' model='null' freemodel='false' databound='true' freeform='false' _initialized='true' originalTitle='Provide value for Output2' xql='.//ID' ref='.//ID' _inTable='true' dataBoundElement='true'></DIV></TD><TD><DIV id=xfe4 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output4 class='input output' title='Value for Output4' readOnly xformstype='output' doEBIValidate='false' __parent='table1' __cID='c516' transactional='true' model='null' freemodel='false' databound='true' freeform='false' _initialized='true' originalTitle='Value for Output4' xql='EMPID' isOutputControl='true' ref='EMPID' _inTable='true' dataBoundElement='true'></DIV></TD><TD><DIV id=xfe6 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output5 class='input output' title='Value for Output5' readOnly xformstype='output' doEBIValidate='false' __parent='table1' __cID='c517' transactional='true' model='null' freemodel='false' databound='true' freeform='false' _initialized='true' originalTitle='Value for Output5' xql='ROLEID' isOutputControl='true' ref='ROLEID' _inTable='true' dataBoundElement='true'></DIV></TD><TD><DIV id=xfe8 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output3 class='input output' title='Value for Output3' readOnly xformstype='output' doEBIValidate='false' __parent='table1' __cID='c518' transactional='true' model='null' freemodel='false' databound='true' freeform='false' _initialized='true' originalTitle='Value for Output3' xql='num1' isOutputControl='true' ref='num1' _inTable='true' dataBoundElement='true'></DIV></TD><TD><DIV id=xfe10 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output1 class='input output' title='Value for Output1' readOnly xformstype='output' doEBIValidate='false' __parent='table1' __cID='c519' transactional='true' model='null' freemodel='false' databound='true' freeform='false' _initialized='true' originalTitle='Value for Output1' xql='num2' isOutputControl='true' ref='num2' _inTable='true' dataBoundElement='true'></DIV></TD></TR>");

 var buttonObject = document.createElement("");
 buttonObject.innerHTML = previousInnerHTML;
```

But output getting is

```
"<INPUT id=check_table1 onclick=WebForm.markRowForSelection(event) type=checkbox xformstype="checkbox" doEBIValidate="false" __cID="c514" transactional="true" model="null" freemodel="false" databound="true" freeform="false" _initialized="true" originalTitle dataBoundElement="true" selectnotifier="true" trueValue="null" falseValue="null"></INPUT></TD><TD>
<DIV id=xfe2 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output2 class=input title="Provide value for Output2" type=text xformstype="input" doEBIValidate="false" __parent="table1" __cID="c515" transactional="true" model="null" freemodel="false" databound="true" freeform="false" _initialized="true" originalTitle="Provide value for Output2" xql=".//ID" ref=".//ID" _inTable="true" dataBoundElement="true"></DIV></TD><TD>
<DIV id=xfe4 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output4 class="input output" title="Value for Output4" readOnly xformstype="output" doEBIValidate="false" __parent="table1" __cID="c516" transactional="true" model="null" freemodel="false" databound="true" freeform="false" _initialized="true" originalTitle="Value for Output4" xql="EMPID" isOutputControl="true" ref="EMPID" _inTable="true" dataBoundElement="true"></DIV></TD><TD>
<DIV id=xfe6 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output5 class="input output" title="Value for Output5" readOnly xformstype="output" doEBIValidate="false" __parent="table1" __cID="c517" transactional="true" model="null" freemodel="false" databound="true" freeform="false" _initialized="true" originalTitle="Value for Output5" xql="ROLEID" isOutputControl="true" ref="ROLEID" _inTable="true" dataBoundElement="true"></DIV></TD><TD>
<DIV id=xfe8 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output3 class="input output" title="Value for Output3" readOnly xformstype="output" doEBIValidate="false" __parent="table1" __cID="c518" transactional="true" model="null" freemodel="false" databound="true" freeform="false" _initialized="true" originalTitle="Value for Output3" xql="num1" isOutputControl="true" ref="num1" _inTable="true" dataBoundElement="true"></DIV></TD><TD>
<DIV id=xfe10 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output1 class="input output" title="Value for Output1" readOnly xformstype="output" doEBIValidate="false" __parent="table1" __cID="c519" transactional="true" model="null" freemodel="false" databound="true" freeform="false" _initialized="true" originalTitle="Value for Output1" xql="num2" isOutputControl="true" ref="num2" _inTable="true" dataBoundElement="true"></DIV></TD></TR>"
```

intial TR and TD element are mising. What could be the reason

Comment: Why do `new String()` instead of `""`?

Comment: tried with "", dint work.. tried another way..thats all...

Comment: Also, why do `x=x.concat(y)` instead of `x=x+y` or even `x+=y`? All work.

Comment: Are you trying to insert tr-td elements inside button element?

Comment: I don't think `document.createElement("")` works.

Comment: document.createElement("") works. Am even able to append it to another node. But Only issue is the intial TR and TD does not come !

Comment: @SanjaiPalliyil how does an anonymous tag look like in the DOM viewer?

Comment: I think at this point you should be building DOM nodes, not creating them from strings. You'll end up with something more readable (your code lacks newlines).

Comment: @JanDvorak var buttonObject = document.createElement(""); will create a an element with null nodeName and if you see butonObject.innerHTML, value will be "" . But i am able to append it to another node. Only isue being the TR and TD missing

Comment: ok ! Can you show me an example of building DOM nodes

Comment: The issue will remain: you can't have TDs inside INPUTs. TDs belong to TRs and TRs belong to TABLEs

Comment: @JanDvorak Plz check my code ... previousInnerHTML.concat( ..... Its clearly given in <TR><TD><Input> format !

Comment: Could it be just a rendering issue? After all, you want the inner HTML of an element with a null tag name. The browser is allowed to freak out.

Comment: @JanDvorak i tried by creating an element without a null tag also...still same output

Comment: @JanDvorak y dnt u try the same code from ur end bfore hypothesizing

Comment: @SanjaiPalliyil can you prepare a _minimal_ test case demonstrating the issue, complete with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Then I would upvote the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert a large chunk of HTML like you're doing, and don't want to replace the entire `.innerHTML` of the parent object (your table), use `.insertAdjacentHTML()`.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Script:

```js
var containerObject = document.getElementById("table1"); 
containerObject.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', "<TR class='evenrow ' __eventAdded='true' isSubTotalRow='false' usable='false' index='40'><TD><INPUT id=check_table1 onclick=WebForm.markRowForSelection(event) type=checkbox xformstype='checkbox' doEBIValidate='false' __cID='c514' transactional='true' model='null' freemodel='false' databound='true' freeform='false' _initialized='true' originalTitle dataBoundElement='true' selectnotifier='true' trueValue='null' falseValue='null'></INPUT></TD><TD><DIV id=xfe2 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output2 class=input title='Provide value for Output2' type=text xformstype='input' doEBIValidate='false' __parent='table1' __cID='c515' transactional='true' model='null' freemodel='false' databound='true' freeform='false' _initialized='true' originalTitle='Provide value for Output2' xql='.//ID' ref='.//ID' _inTable='true' dataBoundElement='true'></DIV></TD><TD><DIV id=xfe4 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output4 class='input output' title='Value for Output4' readOnly xformstype='output' doEBIValidate='false' __parent='table1' __cID='c516' transactional='true' model='null' freemodel='false' databound='true' freeform='false' _initialized='true' originalTitle='Value for Output4' xql='EMPID' isOutputControl='true' ref='EMPID' _inTable='true' dataBoundElement='true'></DIV></TD><TD><DIV id=xfe6 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output5 class='input output' title='Value for Output5' readOnly xformstype='output' doEBIValidate='false' __parent='table1' __cID='c517' transactional='true' model='null' freemodel='false' databound='true' freeform='false' _initialized='true' originalTitle='Value for Output5' xql='ROLEID' isOutputControl='true' ref='ROLEID' _inTable='true' dataBoundElement='true'></DIV></TD><TD><DIV id=xfe8 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output3 class='input output' title='Value for Output3' readOnly xformstype='output' doEBIValidate='false' __parent='table1' __cID='c518' transactional='true' model='null' freemodel='false' databound='true' freeform='false' _initialized='true' originalTitle='Value for Output3' xql='num1' isOutputControl='true' ref='num1' _inTable='true' dataBoundElement='true'></DIV></TD><TD><DIV id=xfe10 class=fieldsbox><INPUT id=output1 class='input output' title='Value for Output1' readOnly xformstype='output' doEBIValidate='false' __parent='table1' __cID='c519' transactional='true' model='null' freemodel='false' databound='true' freeform='false' _initialized='true' originalTitle='Value for Output1' xql='num2' isOutputControl='true' ref='num2' _inTable='true' dataBoundElement='true'></DIV></TD></TR>")
```

#### HTML:

```html
<table id="table1">
</table>
```

Comment: Is this better than `containerObject.innerHTML += string`?

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, it's more efficient, especially on large chunks of existing HTML which have to be entirely rebuilt with `.innerHTML +=`. Also it has other options you can't do with `.innerHTML`: `beforeBegin`, `afterEnd`.

Answer (score 1):

I get an error in the javascript console when trying to create a "blank" DOM element.  You can't do `document.createElement("")`.  It looks like you're trying to create a table so, try this:

```
 var buttonObject = document.createElement("table");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fCBne/

Comment: I suggest "tbody" instead of "table". Otherwise Chrome inserts a `tbody` node around the table contents.

Comment: Hi..I already have a table structure. What am trying to do is include this TR block to it. Hope you get me.

Comment: var containerObject = document.getElementById("table1");
containerObject.childNodes.item(1).appendChild(buttonObject);

Comment: @SanjaiPalliyil perhaps you want to look into `documentFragment`s. They behave exactly like I think you want.